# Firebird, which driver?

Tags: delphi, database-connection, firebird, dbx

Now that I have decided upon [Firebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700824/firebird-or-nexusdb), with the help of StackOverflow :), which driver do you recommend?

- Delphi's DBX
- Another vendor's DBX
- Some native driver

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use DBX since Delphi 6, and Im happy :)

- With Delphi 2010 Im using default Firebird driver - Only available for Enterprise and Architect editions
- Delphi 2006, 2007 and 2009 I have used CoreLabs/DevArt DBX Drivers
- Until Delphi 7 I have used default DBX Interbase driver

Now you can also test this free DBX driver that seems to be very good

- [Download](http://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/)
- [Support](http://groups.google.com/group/dbxfirebird?pli=1)

Answer (score 2):

I usually recommended any database components comes from [Devart](http://www.devart.com/), because they always have been best of their category.

they have two products support FB, which are [IBDac](http://www.devart.com/ibdac/) which is direct access components to IB & FB, and [Unidac](http://www.devart.com/unidac/) which is universal direct access components and has support for IB/FB beside other many like: oracle, SQL server, MySql, PostgreSql and ODBC links too.

Why I recommended them?, because they faster than most of other components, and very stable with great support.

Comment: Thanks for that link - I just learnt that Devart is/was CoreLabs. Cool - their MS SQL Server dbXpress is pretty damn good.

Answer (score 0):

Firebird is a good choice.

Delphi DBX can be good.

You can also investigate some free [JVUIB](http://www.progdigy.com) or some you need to pay [FIBPlus](http://www.devrace.com) - [IBDac](http://www.devart.com) - [IBObjects](http://www.ibobjects.com)

and others [there](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq7/)